# How to cancel part of my flight

Tags: air-travel, cancellations

I am flying with AirCanada

```
Toronto -> Zurich
Zurich -> Milan MXP
```

and back to Toronto

```
Milan -> Montreal
Montreal -> Toronto
```

Ticket booked through my company and everything is ok

Now..

I am thinking of making some changes.

I want to take the train from Zurich to Milan instead of a flight

What is the best way to do that?

I know that if you did not show up for one flight the whole trip would be cancelled.

is there any safe way to do that without risking the rest of the trip?

Comment: Important to notice: if you simply don't show up for that leg, the complete return trip will probably be null and voided, without compensation. Don't try it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to change the flight to what is called an “open jaw”: you arrive in one city (Zurich) and return from another (Milan).

If the ticket is flexible and allows changes this should be doable (though there may be fees and/or a price difference).

Note that counter-intuitively, it might be more expensive: direct flights (Toronto-Zurich) are usually more expensive than those with a connection (Toronto-Milano via Zurich).

It’s likely you won’t be able to make the change online. Depending on how it was booked, you’ll probably have to contact the travel agent or call the airline.

You may also want to check if your company doesn’t have a policy prohibiting that for whatever reason.